# Test if the columns in a row are equal ina dataframe

Tags: r

I have a file as below:

```
Item Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
1    JP   JP   JP
2    BP   BP   XP
3    LP   LP   LP
```

I would like to check for the condition to see if Loc1 == Loc2 == Loc3 (Actually i have lot more columns)

hence the output I am expecting is:

```
Item Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Out
1    JP   JP   JP   TRUE
2    BP   BP   XP   FALSE
3    LP   LP   LP   TRUE
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a reproducible example . Try with `data(mtcars)`

Comment: What's the @$@#$@# deal with editing & deleting my answer @Ashwin?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I was also very confused as to why your answer only had the reproducible data and not an actual response.

Comment: It's unlikely I'll ever even look at a question posed Ashwin again, @brittenb, let alone burn cycles answering it.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yeah, completely unacceptable behavior on their behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reproducible example in @hrbrmstr's reponse, one approach would be the following:

```
product <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Loc1 <- c("NY","DN","CO","MI")
Loc2 <- c("NY","DN","CO","MI")
Loc3 <- c("NY","DN","PH","MI")
Loc4 <- c("NY","LA","CO","MI")
Loc5 <- c("NY","DN","CO","MI")

df <- data.frame(product, Loc1, Loc2, 
                 Loc3, Loc4, Loc5, 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

df$out <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
df
#   product Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Loc4 Loc5   out
# 1       A   NY   NY   NY   NY   NY  TRUE
# 2       B   DN   DN   DN   LA   DN FALSE
# 3       C   CO   CO   PH   CO   CO FALSE
# 4       D   MI   MI   MI   MI   MI  TRUE
```

This approach loops through `df` row by row and checks for the number of unique values in the location columns. If they're all identical, the length will be 1, so the check returns `TRUE` if they're all identical and `FALSE` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

To account for all the columns:

```
read.table(text="Item Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
1    JP   JP   JP
2    BP   BP   XP
3    LP   LP   LP", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

df$Out <- apply(df, 1, function(x) { length(unique(x[-1]))==1 })

print(df)

##   Item Loc1 Loc2 Loc3   Out
## 1    1   JP   JP   JP  TRUE
## 2    2   BP   BP   XP FALSE
## 3    3   LP   LP   LP  TRUE
```

Comment: i'm flagging this malfeasance unless you roll it back

Comment: I've rolled it back on my own and flagged you to the mods @Ashwin

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
 !rowSums(!df1[-1]==df1[2][row(df1[-1])])
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```